# Getting serial port name from USB device's serial number

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, usb, hardware

Is there a way to get the '/dev/cu.*' port name from a USB device's serial number?

I'm using the following command to get the serial number:

```
system_profiler SPUSBDataType | grep "Serial Number"
```

I'm having a problem where the port name in '/dev/cu.*' keeps changing whenever I plug/unplug a USB and I'm trying to map via the serial number.

Comment: I was not able to determine a way to fully answer your question, but I recommend looking at the output of `ioreg -l -p IOUSB` and see if that can help.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish ultimately?  I'm doing data collection where I need to redirect output to a USB serial port.  I'm fortunate in that I know there will only be one USB serial device (mine) connected, so I do "SERPORT=$(ls /dev/cu.usbmodem*) and then I can do things like "cat spoo > $SERPORT" to exfil data to my serial device.  If the port name is changing on subsequent connections (I've seen this too) the serial number isn't likely going to help.